# After upgrading wxpython version: failed at ..\..\src\msw\bitmap.cpp(754) in wxBitmap::DoCreate(): invalid bitmap size

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I was using wxpython version 4.0.7 and built the whole project.
I upgraded version to 4.1.0 i.e. latest wx version.
When I am running the code this error is showing on console but everything else is running fine.

> File "C:\Anaconda\envs\VSTS_24_01_2020_Animation_Started\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py", line 784, in _onSize
> self.bitmap = wx.Bitmap(self._width, self._height)
> wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion ""w > 0 && h > 0"" failed at ....\src\msw\bitmap.cpp(754) in wxBitmap::DoCreate(): invalid bitmap size

Do I need to change the code for bitmap buttons or is there other way to solve this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well and fixed it by avoiding negative number for bitmap size:

```
-        self.frame_1_toolbar.SetToolBitmapSize(wx.Size(-1,30))
+        self.frame_1_toolbar.SetToolBitmapSize(wx.Size(40,40))
```

This issue is also discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/-3FO29vwtzk